# Adding Date Labels to a HighCharts line graph

Tags: javascript, xml, highcharts

I am trying to create a line graph that includes dates along the x-axis. My graph looks like this.
[image]

The array of data looks like this: `[[1376092800000,1],[1379376000000,2],[1380585600000,3],[1383350400000,4],[1383350400000,5],[1383350400000,6],[1383350400000,7],[1383350400000,8],[1385942400000,9],[1385942400000,10],[1385942400000,11],[1385942400000,12],[1388620800000,13],[1388620800000,14],[1388620800000,15],[1388620800000,16],[1391212800000,17],[1393632000000,18],[1401580800000,19],[1401580800000,20],[1401580800000,21],[1404172800000,22],[1404172800000,23]]`

The first value in the array is supposed to plot a point at (August 2013, 1); however, instead it is plotting the first point at January 1st. I would like to match my data with the values in my array. I also would like the x-axis to show the month followed by the year. I have tried adding

```
labels: {
    formatter: function () {
        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%m %y', this.value);
    }
}
```

but this just changes the x-axis to 
[image]

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT**

I think the problem has something to do with the way I am accessing the data. I am calling an XML file that has the date values. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zr4L1c1/) of a working graph except the data is hard-coded in. I would like a way to pass the data into page.

**MY CODE**

```
//Open the XML file
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://atlanticresearchgroupinc.quickbase.com/db/bi6vng8r5?a=API_DoQuery&clist=a", false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

var record = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("record");
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var dataset = [];

//Create dataset
for (var i = 0; i < record.length; i++) {
    x = record[i].getElementsByTagName("date_of_consent")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    y = y + 1;
    var newArray = [x, y];
    dataset.push(newArray);
}

$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Enrollment Over Time',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Date of Enrollment'
            },
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Number of Patients'
            },
            min: 0,
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
            pointFormat: '{point.x:%e. %b}: {point.y:.2f} Patients'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Actual Enrollment',
            data: dataset
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle so to show your entire code? The data is in the wrong format, but it doesn't match with how I'd expect your graph to look (I'd expect it to zig-zag, but yours is a linear increase).

Comment: @Ondkloss I fixed the data in the question

Comment: That data looks valid. It must be something else in your code causing it. Are you certain that data causes the scenario in your screenshot? A JSFiddle would make this easier to debug.

Comment: A "as basic as it gets" demo of your data: http://jsfiddle.net/rkrvmg16/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your example data array it is correct, as shown by example in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rkrvmg16/).

The problem (as you might've discovered) is that getting it from XML is slightly different.  In your code you have this line in your `for` loop:

```
x = record[i].getElementsByTagName("date_of_consent")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

The problem here is that JavaScript (and Highcharts) doesn't know that you intend this to be a integer. It is fetched as a string. And inserting strings as timestamps in your data array doesn't work in Highcharts.

You will have to parse this `x` value to an integer and then push it to your array, for example:

```
x = parseInt(record[i].getElementsByTagName("date_of_consent")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

This should make Highcharts see them as timestamps and show the correct dates on the x-axis. When it gets strings it just treats the data as having increasing x-values from 0, 1, 2...

Hope this resolves your problems.